# Adjective "to do with weather"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, adjectives

I'd like an adjective that means "to do with weather" in the same way that dramaturgical means "to do with dramaturgy."

> The _______ imagery is ...

I swear the word is right on the tip of my tongue, is it similar (in spelling) to "temperamental"?

Comment: Also, just to make the question seem more interesting to others, you may want to mention that the obvious adjective [weathery](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/weathery) means something else entirely in Merriam-Webster's New International Dictionary Third Edition. It's the same definition as is on their website.

Comment: Looking into all the entries containing the word "weather" in two bulky dictionaries (Shorter Oxford English Dictionary/ Webster's Third New International Dictionary) has yielded an unlikely candidate-"synoptic"; wondering whether you have managed to retrieve the word that had once slipped your mind?

Answer (score 6):

The word is ***meteorological***.

[Oxford Online:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/meteorological)

> Relating to the branch of science concerned with the processes and phenomena of the atmosphere, especially as a means of forecasting the weather.
>
> ‘detailed meteorological data’
> ‘the effect of global warming on meteorological conditions’

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "climatic," but I still think there's another one beginning with 't'.

> ## climatic
>
> /klʌɪˈmatɪk/
>
> *adjective*
> relating to climate.

[Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/climatic).

Comment: I love that you just completely made up a source... and it doesn't even match the text...

Comment: Hmm, you're right. I was a little hasty with this one. 'Twas my mistake (twice). It should be fixed *now*. Bleh...